# Keep all footnotes in one paragraph in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-office-2016, footnote

I'm using MS Office Professional 2016 and I'm facing the following problem: I have some footnotes in one page of a word document, but each one of them occupies its own paragraph. What I want to have is one single paragraph containing all the footnotes, rather than one paragraph per footnote. How am I supposed to do it? Here's an example of the footnotes I have:

```
1.Zhao et al., 2021. 
2.Smith & Johnson, 2022.
```

And what I'd like to have instead:

```
1.Zhao et al., 2021. 2.Smith & Johnson, 2022.
```

Comment: I doubt that such a thing is possible. Moreover if it's exist will make footnotes unreadable. Instead of "walk" vertically to get the number you should scroll long sentence.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered with a suggestion to use columns in the Microsoft Answers forum. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/keep-all-footnotes-in-one-paragraph/a1606da1-08bb-4501-b7e4-d67dc5416d72 Please and follow the guidelines for cross-posting etiquette. https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184 .

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to merge footnotes as follows :

- Click on the `¶` button on the toolbar to
  enable the display of non-printing characters
- Select the paragraph mark at the end of footnote 1 and format
  it as hidden (Font > Hidden)
- Repeat for the other footnotes
- Click again on the `¶` button to disable non-printing characters.

The result will look like :

[image]

Note that it can happen that this won't conserve any
vertical space, if Word calculates the vertical size of
the footnotes without noticing the hidden end-of-paragraph.
If that happens, you'll get a blank area following the "merged" notes.

To do better than the above will require a VBA macro to truly merge
the footnotes into one, although that solution has its own problem
in that it destroys the connection between the text and the footnotes.
If interested, see the article
[Combining Footnotes](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013767_Combining_Footnotes.html).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @harrymc, Where are you finding that symbol? Is that supposed to be the paragraph mark you find in the `Home` menu and `paragraph` submenu? Also, where do you find the `hidden` font? Is that a customer font that needs to be downloaded?

Comment: @Brian: Yes, ribbon pane Home, group Paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create footnotes (end of page) or endnotes (end of document) but either way that will each  occupy their own line (or paragraph as you put it). It is not possible to do what you want. Additionally, formatting it the way you want is not compatible with any literary footnoting format.

source: https://www.simuldocs.com/blog/how-to-change-the-layout-and-formatting-of-footnotes-in-microsoft-word

source: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_endnotes_and_footnotes.html

Comment: Thank you Brian!